# Cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1 python undetected-chromedriver

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Running the following on a machine running Ubuntu 22.094 LTS:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path='/home/samuel04/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I get the following error: `Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:42129`

How could I fix this? My chromedriver and chrome are both on version 108 and undetected-chromedriver is 3.2.1.

Comment: Are you confusing the localhost IP address `127.0.0.1` with a chrome (driver) version?

Comment: @KlausD. Oh my I think so. I still don't understand what the problem could be though.